# How to get next immediate node from the selected node of the Treeview in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, treeview

I have a TreeView in C# Windows Form. If the user selected one node, then I want to retrieve the immediate next node and also immediate previous node of the treeview. Don't consider if it is sibling or any other. I want to just pick up immediate next node and also immediate previous node.

See this picture:

[image]

Suppose user Selecting following case ==>    I want to retrieve this node

1. 0 1.Sample Data                          ==>1 When multiple agents...
2. 1 When multiple agents...                ===>2 The second major ...
3. 2 The second major ...                   ===>3 In this case....
4. 3 In this case....                       ===>4 2.Target Settings...

and so on..

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `e.Node.NextNode` and `e.Node.PrevNode` for sibling node.

[TreeNode.NextNode Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.nextnode.aspx)

[TreeNode.PrevNode Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.prevnode.aspx)

**EDIT**

or `e.Node.NextVisibleNode` and `e.Node.PrevVisibleNode` in your case for visible node.

[TreeNode.NextVisibleNode Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.nextvisiblenode.aspx)

[TreeNode.PrevVisibleNode Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.prevvisiblenode.aspx)

please refer to MSDN for other `TreeNode` properties: [TreeNode Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3w7e5fat.aspx)

Comment: nextNode or prevNode returns only of its sibling node... I want immediate next and prev node... Please see updated question for more details...

Comment: use `PrevVisibleNod`e and `NextVisibleNode` then, see my updates

Comment: @Saravanan, so just make your program expand the treeview before check the next/prev node then.

Comment: So what's the problem? With the information above, I'm sure you can combine those properties and get what you requested.

Comment: e.g. if all your nodes are collapsed, and you are on `0 1.Sample Data`, you just need to expand your selected node (in this case `0 1.Sample Data`) and use `NextVisibleNode` property to get `1 When multiple agents...` . After this if you want, you can restore it back to collapse (if it was).

Comment: @Bolu:Ok I will try and let u know... Thanks a lot

Comment: Remember to use `SuspendLayout` to avoid blinking. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.suspendlayout.aspx

Answer (score 2):

```
TreeView tr = new TreeView();

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tr.AfterSelect += new TreeViewEventHandler(tr_AfterSelect);
}

void tr_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    TreeNode PrevNode = e.Node.PrevNode;
    TreeNode NextNode = e.Node.NextNode;
}
```

For the cases you can do this :

```
void tr_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{

    TreeNode NextNode;

    if (e.Node.Nodes.Count == 0)
    {
        NextNode = e.Node.NextNode;
    }
    else 
    {
        NextNode = e.Node.Nodes[0]; 
    }
}
```

Comment: nextNode or prevNode returns only of its sibling node... I want immediate next and prev node... Please see updated question for more details...

Answer (score 1):

I've stumbled across this question having the same issue, so here's my solution to the issue:

Assuming **start** is the TreeNode to begin with, going "down"

```
if (start?.Nodes.Count > 0)
    start = start?.Nodes[0]; //If there are childs, select the first
else if (start?.NextNode != null)
    start = start?.NextNode; //If there is a sibling, select the sibling
else
{
    //In this case, the next node is a sibling of one of the nodes ancestors
    if (start?.Parent?.NextNode != null)
        start = start?.Parent?.NextNode; //the parents sibling is our next node
    else
    {
        //we go the paths along the parents up, until we can go to the next sibling,
        //as long as there exist some parents
        while(start.Level != 0)
        {
            start = start.Parent;
            if (start.NextNode != null)
            {
                start = start.NextNode;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works perfectly in my opinion. NextVisibleNode - solves the problem

```
if (treeView.SelectedNode != null) {
    var currentNode = treeView.SelectedNode;
    while(currentNode.NextVisibleNode != null ) {
        currentNode = currentNode.NextVisibleNode;    
        if (currentNode.Checked) { break; }
    }
    MessageBox.Show("Next checked node is " + currentNode.Text);
}
```